# Docker - nginx proxy - access hosts between containers

Tags: nginx, docker, virtualization, docker-compose, docker-network

I have web application.

1. Public web app (app1)
2. api web app (app2)

I make docker configuration for this apps. Each application in its container. To access this applications from web, configured container with nginx, where nginx proxy all requests.
So i can run - http://app1.dev/ and http://app2.dev/

But i need have access from app1 to http://app2.dev/ (access hosts app2.dev from app1 container).

Ping (from app1 container):

```
PING app2.dev (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
```

What i should configure else, to have access to http://app2.dev/ host from app1 container?

Nginx proxy config

```
upstream app1_upstream {
    server app1;
}
upstream app1_upstream {
    server app2;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app1.dev
                app2.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        if ($host = "app1.dev") {
            proxy_pass http://app1;
        }

        if ($host = "app2.dev") {
            proxy_pass http://app2;
        }
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/proxy_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy_access.log;
}
```

Docker compose

```
version: '2'
services:
    proxy:
        build: ./proxy/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - app1
            - app2
            - app1:app1
            - app2:app2
        hostname: proxy

    app1:
        build: ./app1/
        volumes:
            - ../app1/:/var/www/app1
        hostname: app1

    app2:
        build: ./app2/
        volumes:
            - ../app2/:/var/www/app2
        hostname: app2
```

`docker-compose ps`

```
app1      /sbin/my_init  Up      80/tcp                                   
app2     /sbin/my_init  Up      80/tcp                                   
proxy_1   /sbin/my_init  Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of docker you running, but if you are (or are able to) run 1.10 you should use a docker network instead of using "link".

If you run all three containers on the same docker network then they will have access to one another through their container name.

That will allow you to make the call from app1 to app2 without going back through your proxy (although I would call that an anti-pattern as if you were to change the interface to app2 you would have to update app1 and the proxy, I would have app1 call app2 through your proxy so you maintain one interface).

For more info on Docker networks:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

TLDR:

```
# create bridge network (for single host)
docker networks create my-network
```

then change your compose too:

```
version: '2'
services:
    proxy:
        build: ./proxy/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            - my-network
        hostname: proxy

    app1:
        build: ./app1/
        volumes:
            - ../app1/:/var/www/app1
        networks:
            - my-network
        hostname: app1

    app2:
        build: ./app2/
        volumes:
            - ../app2/:/var/www/app2
        networks:
            - my-network
        hostname: app2

networks:
   my-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: Hi there!
I tried the same thing, but didn't work for me. Nginx still can't resolve the names. Am I missing something permission wise?

Comment: I think you meant docker **network** create my-network (without an s)

Answer (score 0):

```
ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
```

exposes ports to the host machine. When you do

```
docker ps -a
```

you will see these ports listed

However, to expose ports between containers you need to use the EXPOSE command in your dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

```
What i should configure else, to have access to http://app2.dev/ host from app1 container?
```

You must EXPOSE ports in dockerfile!

also if you do a ...

```
docker exec -it containerName bash
```

you will be able to explore.

View the hosts file inside the container.

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

you will see an entry for the other container in the hosts file if you have --link the containers correctly.

you can ping using the domain name in the hosts file.

Comment: i've updated question. There no problems with ports. I can access applications from web.

Comment: each container hosts file contains record only for this container
`172.19.0.8 proxy` (this is for proxy, for app1 and app2 their own ip)

But you can see docker-compose file - is there incorrect linking?

Each app Dockerfile contains -  `EXPOSE 80`